# Passing 'this' scope to callback function

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm trying to pass 'this' to a callback function. I know a "suitable" way of doing this is setting this to a variable and using the variable... but that's not very elegant.

```
var that = this;
chrome.storage.sync.set(this.defaultOptions, function () {
    that.loadOptions();
});
```

I'm trying something else, but I can't figure out how to do it. Here's what I have tried:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set(this.defaultOptions, (function () {
    this.loadOptions();
}).call(this));
```

But it's not working out. I'm getting this error:

```
Error in response to storage.set: Error: Invocation of form 
get(object, undefined) doesn't match definition 
get(optional string or array or object keys, function callback)
```

Other questions on SO I've tried looking into have similar needs but not quite the same. How can I achieve what I want in the best way?

Comment: `}).bind(this));` will bind the scope of the function without executing it immediately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) then:

```
do_this((function() {
    returh this.test + 5;
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: I've updated the question to the exact code, and namely I'm (still) getting this error: `Error in response to storage.set: Error: Invocation of form get(object, undefined) doesn't match definition get(optional string or array or object keys, function callback)` (though I have to admit my IDE likes `bind`)

Comment: I did in my tests, I just didn't put bind in the question to avoid confusion. Both with call and bind I still get this error

Comment: Put the bind method in your question, so that I could see if there's any problem...may be you're using bind method wrongly...

Comment: My bad, this fixed it, the error was repeating in another place that did the same, I updated that and it worked. Thanks! I'll accept the answer when I'm allowed

Answer (score 0):

Use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), as mentioned by Bhojendra Nepal.

```
function callback() {
  return this.test + 5;
}

do_this(callback.bind(this));
```