# Firestore Document Deletion Issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, angular5, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with firestore, where i've written a service code to delete the document from one of the collection.

## Service Code:

**firestore.service.ts**

```
    deleteFromCollection(id: string){
        this.eventDoc = this.afs.doc(`bookings/${id}`);
        return this.eventDoc.delete();
    }
```

## Main Code:

**blank.component.ts**

```
    deleteData(){
        let audio = new Audio();
        audio.src= "./assets/app/media/sound/to-the-point.mp3";
        audio.load();

        this._firestoreService.deleteFromCollection(this.eventToShow.id).
        then(function(){
           this.closeEditModal();
           audio.play(); 
           this.showToastr("Deletion Done Successfully"); 
        }).
        catch(function(error){
           this.closeEditModal();
           audio.play(); 
           this.showToastr("Deletion Error"); 
        });   
    }


    showToastr(msg){
        this.message = true;
        this.deletionMessage = msg;
        setTimeout(() => this.message = false, 5000);
    }

    closeEditModal(){
        $('#edit_modal').removeClass('show');
    }
```

So when i'm using the above code the deletion is performed, but then section is not able to call showToastr/closeEditModal method which already present in BlankComponent Class.

It's giving this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'closeEditModal' of undefined.

and same error for showToastr method.

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Inside of a callback function, the meaning of `this` changes to that specific function. This means that in your line `this.showToastr(...)`, the `this` refers to the local callback function which doesn't have a `showToastr` method.

The simplest solution is to create a shadow variable for the correct value of `this`:

```
   var that = this;
   this._firestoreService.deleteFromCollection(this.eventToShow.id).
    then(function(){
       that.closeEditModal();
       audio.play(); 
       that.showToastr("Deletion Done Successfully"); 
    }).
    catch(function(error){
       that.closeEditModal();
       audio.play(); 
       that.showToastr("Deletion Error"); 
    });
```

I recommend that you read some of these too, since this problem has been covered before (and way better than I can):

- [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work/3127440#3127440)
- [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)
- [Maintaining the reference to "this" in Javascript when using callbacks and closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874723/maintaining-the-reference-to-this-in-javascript-when-using-callbacks-and-closu)
- [Passing 'this' scope to callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28300796/passing-this-scope-to-callback-function)
- [javascript how to get this.variable in callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670359/javascript-how-to-get-this-variable-in-callback-function)